# Did someone break into my email account?

Tags: gmail

I just got the following email (and another similar one):

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software. Your email message was not delivered as is to the intended recipients because malware was detected in one or more attachments included with it. All attachments were deleted.

--- Additional Information ---:

Subject: sport
Sender: erelsgl@gmail.com

Time received: 9/1/2016 1:32:05 AM
Message ID:<000101d20422$ec2b823e$c0a80001@61.141.118.205>
Detections found:
veksport.zip     JS/Nemucod.TSF

________________________________


Wydawnictwo: Express Media Sp. z o.o., 85-058 Bydgoszcz, ul. Warszawska 13, tel. 0048 52 3226201, zarzad@expressmedia.pl, Sąd Rejonowy w Bydgoszczy, XIII Wydział Gospodarczy Krajowego Rejestru Sądowego, KRS 0000022049, NIP: 967-10-55-458, Kapitał zakładowy: 43 508 640,00 zł, BRE Bank SA 58114010520000594180001001
Treść niniejszej wiadomości jest poufna i przeznaczona wyłącznie dla jej adresatów. W razie pomyłkowego przesłania Państwu tej wiadomości, prosimy o poinformowanie o tym nadawcy przez wysłanie odpowiedzi zwrotnej. Rozpowszechnianie, kopiowanie, rozprowadzanie lub inne działanie o podobnym charakterze bez zgody nadawcy jest zabronione i może być karalne.

Wydawnictwo: Express Media Sp. z o.o., 85-058 Bydgoszcz, ul. Warszawska 13, Poland, phone: 0048 52 3226201, zarzad@expressmedia.pl, District Court of Bydgoszcz, XIII Commercial Department of the National Court Register under No: 0000022049, VAT No: PL 967-10-55-458. Share capital: PLN 43 508 640,00, BRE Bank SA 58114010520000594180001001
The content of this message is confidential and is intended solely for its addressees. If you have received this message by mistake, please notify the sender immediately by replying to this message. Any disclosure, copying, distribution or any action taken or omitted to be taken without authorization in reliance on it is prohibited and may be unlawful.
```

I never sent any such email, and have not find such email in my Sent Items box.

Is it possible that someone broke into my gmail account and sent a malicious email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a spammer spoofed their sender address, using your e-mail address instead of their own. Note that the subject of the mail is simply "sport" and the contents is a .zip file. This smells like spam.

What probably happened is that at least one of the intended receiving addresses didn't exist. The domain of the address did exist, however, and the mail server sent an error message to the apparent sender address - yours. It happens.

If the mail had been in your "Sent items" box, then yes, you'd probably been hacked.
The reverse does not hold, unfortunately - if you were hacked and a spammer (or botnet) sent a mail from your address, they might have removed the evidence.

However, I think the spammer just used your e-mail address for a mail they sent from their own machine.

Still, it won't hurt to change your password, just in case. And maybe apply 2-factor authentication on your e-mail as well, if you haven't already.